# I'm getting a StackOverflowError that recursively calls the same error

Tags: java, oop, compiler-errors, stack-overflow

I'm not sure what is wrong with my program. Essentially I just want to make an object of my class. Then that object should create *another* object inside its constructor. But when I create the object from inside of the first object's constructor, I get the error:

> "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError  at
>   Setup.(Setup.java:31)   at
>   GameController.(GameController.java:30)"

This section of the error repeats until my runtime 'error' box is full:

> "at Setup.(Setup.java:31)
>   at GameController.(GameController.java:30)"

Here is my code: (Object that is created in main)

```
public class GameController {
GameController() {   
Setup Set = new Setup(); //Refers to error happening here.
```

(Set Object Class)

```
public class Setup extends GameController {
Setup() { //Refers to error happening here.
```

I don't mind doing my code differently but I'd like to know what I'm doing wrong so I can do it right in the future.

Comment: Make up your mind. *Either* you are getting a `StackOverflowException` *or* it does not compile. The two are mutually exclusive.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Don't have Setup extend GameController! This is what's causing the unwanted recursion and is likely not necessary.

When you create a Setup object, it calls GameController's constructor, which creates a Setup object which then calls GameController's constructor, which creates a Setup object which then calls GameController's constructor, which creates a Setup object which then calls GameController's constructor, which creates a Setup object which then calls GameController's constructor, which creates a Setup object which then calls GameController's constructor, which creates a Setup object which then calls ....

ad infinitum.

I suspect that you're using inheritance for inappropriate reasons here, and so again, simply don't have Setup extend GameController and this problem should be fixed.

---

Regarding,

> Oh, and it does NOT compile.

Impossible. If it didn't compile and run, you couldn't see this exception.

Comment: I wasn't aware it was calling both constructors over and over, this makes sense now.


Thank you very much!

Comment: @Zag: you're welcome. Understand that every child class will call every super class's constructor when it is created. Why does Setup extend GameController in the first place? If it's to gain access to GameController's variable's, then that would be very inappropriate and would not work.

Comment: @Zag: also why did you state that your code didn't compile? This is an impossibility.

Comment: I call some functions within GameController which I didn't want to make public, and instead wanted to have them as protected. The issue I'm having now is that I'm trying to do GameController.<function> but the issue is that I'd have to make the function a static function which I don't want to do. I'd rather use my object I first instantiated like, object.<function> but It can't see it in the Setup class yet, which is what I'm working on currently.

Comment: @Zag: don't make it static. You can always pass references, including passing in a GameController method into Setup via Setup's constructor. Then use the parameter to set a GameController field within Setup.